# PHP/Ajax Chat/MYSql - Create fake users in chat room

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, arrays, chat

I am using Ajax Free Chat on my server. 
I would like to have a couple of fake users logged in to get things going. But I dont know how to implement these using PHP/mysql.

I have found there is a database table called 'online' which displays the logged in users on the user list within the chat. Maybe its this table I need to edit?
Any help reatly appreciated.

```
function addToOnlineList() {
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO '.$this->getDataBaseTable('online').'(
        userID,
        userName,
        userRole,
        channel,
        dateTime,
        ip
    )
    VALUES (
        '.$this->db->makeSafe($this->getUserID()).',
        '.$this->db->makeSafe($this->getUserName()).',
        '.$this->db->makeSafe($this->getUserRole()).',
        '.$this->db->makeSafe($this->getChannel()).',
        NOW(),
        '.$this->db->makeSafe($this->ipToStorageFormat($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])).'
    );';
```

Comment: you want the fake user to chat or just go online ?!

Comment: For now I need them to be in the list of online users situated at the side of the chat applet. They dont need to say anything yet. Maybe a possibility I can make them do quizzes in future when my coding skills are better. But for now just names in the online list will suffice.

Comment: when you insert the values what happen ?

Comment: How do you mean? I havent done anything to the table yet. I dont know how.

Comment: Well that's what you need to do. Read up on how to use MySQL from PHP. Or easier, you could use a web interface like PHPMyAdmin to go modify the records directly.

Comment: Yeah, I have PhpMyadmin, I dont know how to query mysql at the moment. Dont have time to learn, just want to know how to do it for now.

Answer (score 0):

According to your comments that what you should do

First you need to get sure that you are connected to the database if not 
use this

```
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
mysql_select_db("dbname",$connection);
```

next

```
function addToOnlineList() {
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO '.$this->getDataBaseTable('online').'(
        userID,
        userName,
        userRole,
        channel,
        dateTime,
        ip
    )
    VALUES (
        '.$this->db->makeSafe($this->getUserID()).',
        '.$this->db->makeSafe($this->getUserName()).',
        '.$this->db->makeSafe($this->getUserRole()).',
        '.$this->db->makeSafe($this->getChannel()).',
        NOW(),
        '.$this->db->makeSafe($this->ipToStorageFormat($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])).'
    );';
//here what you should add 
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());



}
```

If you know what the values like `$this->getUserID()` the above will work 
if not you should replace them with some values from you 
Good Luck if you need more help just comment

Edit 
this is how you can generate a simple data

```
$names = array("namee1","name2","name3","will");
echo $names[array_rand($names)];
```

Comment: I dont understand how copying the query from the php file will put predefined users in the user list.

Comment: You should define them or generate them :)

Comment: Okie, I dont know how to do that thats why Im asking here.

Comment: you can make an array of each value lets say names 
$names = array("namee1","name2","name3","will");
then select a random one from it see the update

Comment: I dont know if that is correct. I need someone else to clarify.

Comment: Its cool, I found I can insert users in the tables with 'insert' option in myphp admin :)